# How to extract data from database to different excel sheets using vbscript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to extract data from 4 table data from sql server to different excel sheet using vbscript, now I only able to extract one table to one sheet only, I have no idea how to extract another table to another sheet. Above is my code, it is work to first sheet, but second sheet is blank while run bat file. Appreciate for your help!

```
RecordsetSqlServer.Open SQLStatement, ConnectionSqlServer
SQLStatement = "SELECT col1, col2,col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM [table1] table1"
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet1")
With objSheet

Do while NOT RecordsetSqlServer.Eof 

' objSheet.Cells(row,1).Value = 1
objSheet.Cells(row,2).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col1").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,3).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col2").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,4).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col3").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,5).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col4").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,6).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col5").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,7).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col5").Value) * CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col6").Value)
row = row + 1

RecordsetSqlServer.MoveNext

Loop

End with
```

Comment: Because `RecordsetSqlServer.Eof ` is true. Are you just trying to make a second copy of data on a second sheet? what decides what goes on the second sheet?

Comment: Hi Nick, I have 4 table in sql server, and these 4 table need to extract to one excel file which include of 4 different sheet. I had successfully extract 1 table to one sheet only, but have no idea how to extract the 2nd table data to 2nd sheet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include this information. You missed out on the code that initialises `RecordsetSqlServer`. That's the one that picks the table. Note in your existing code you don't have any tables names defined anywhere. How is it meant to know which table goes on to sheet 2? You have to first set up `RecordsetSqlServer` to read from that table. That will set the recordset back to the start and your loop will work.

Comment: So means that, if I want to extract to second sheet, it need to have 2 RecordsetSqlServer to define the table name?

Comment: No I think you can reuse the same one. Somewhere in your code, you have something that sets `RecordsetSqlServer` to a specific table. You need to reuse that code to set it to the correct table before you write to the sheet. At this point you need to edit your question and supply all information _and_ supply all _code_

Comment: I had edited my question, I had tried add another "with objsheet2" and second sheet name, but while run bat file, sheet 2 is blank.

Comment: In your current code, you use the variable `SQLStatement` in the first line but you don't set it till the line after so I don't even know how this code works. Anyway I'll post somehing for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two sets of code for you to review. (Note: not debugged or tested)

A. The short way:

```
SQLStatement = "SELECT col1, col2,col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM [table1] table1"
' Note I moved your code around so that the sql statement 
' is defined before we open the recordset
RecordsetSqlServer.Open SQLStatement, ConnectionSqlServer
objWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset RecordsetSqlServer
RecordsetSqlServer.Close

SQLStatement = "SELECT col1, col2,col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM [table2] table2"
RecordsetSqlServer.Open SQLStatement, ConnectionSqlServer
objWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset RecordsetSqlServer
```

B. An extension of the way you were doing it - not recommended

```
SQLStatement = "SELECT col1, col2,col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM [table1] table1"
' Note I moved your code around so that the sql statement 
' is defined before we open the recordset
RecordsetSqlServer.Open SQLStatement, ConnectionSqlServer
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet1") 

' This line is not necessary. Remove it
' With objSheet

Do while NOT RecordsetSqlServer.Eof 

' objSheet.Cells(row,1).Value = 1
objSheet.Cells(row,2).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col1").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,3).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col2").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,4).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col3").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,5).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col4").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,6).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col5").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,7).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col5").Value) * CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col6").Value)
row = row + 1

RecordsetSqlServer.MoveNext

Loop

' This line is not necessary. Remove it    
' End with

' This is where your original code finished
' Now we close the recordset 
RecordsetSqlServer.Close
' and open it again aganst the next table
SQLStatement = "SELECT col1, col2,col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM [table2]"
RecordsetSqlServer.Open SQLStatement, ConnectionSqlServer
' Set a reference to the next sheet
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet2")

' Because we closed and reopened the recordset, 
' this line is now true (we aren't at the end)
Do while NOT RecordsetSqlServer.Eof 

' objSheet.Cells(row,1).Value = 1
objSheet.Cells(row,2).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col1").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,3).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col2").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,4).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col3").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,5).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col4").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,6).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col5").Value)
objSheet.Cells(row,7).Value = CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col5").Value) * CStr(RecordsetSqlServer.Fields("col6").Value)
row = row + 1

RecordsetSqlServer.MoveNext

Loop

' Close the recordset
RecordsetSqlServer.Close
```

Comment: Hi Nick, appreciate your help, but unfortunately is not work. Coz the sqlstatement I defined early at the top, and then I use call function to loop the number into correct column that I set. Is it the bad way to do this? do you have any best suggestion? so sorry coz I am beginner on vbs.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you get an error when you use the first code? What specifically is the problem?